# Upper bound for different sums having the same value

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $\Lambda :=\{\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n\}$ be a set of $n$ distinct real numbers.

For a given $p \in \mathbb N$, consider further the set

$$I_p := \{  \{i_1, i_2, \dots, i_p\} : i_j \in \{1, \dots,n\} \text{ for all } j=1, \dots, p\}.$$

It is not hard to see that $|I_p| = \binom{n+p-1}{p}$. For example, if $n=3$ and $p=2$, then

$$ I_2 = \{ \{1,1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,3\} \}.$$

Now for a given $p \in \mathbb N$ we write down all $\binom{n+p-1}{p}$ sums
$$\lambda_{i_1} + \lambda_{i_2} + \dots + \lambda_{i_p}. $$

Clearly it can happen that "different" sums have the same value, e.g. if

$$\Lambda = \{0,1,2\}$$

and $p=2$, then we get the sums $0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4$ given by considering the elements of $I_2$.

My question is the following: Is there in general an upper bound on how many "different" sums there are that lead to one particular value?

Another interesting question would be the following: Given a fixed upper bound $N^*$, are there conditions on $\Lambda$ such that for all $p \in \mathbb N$, at most $N^*$ different $p$'th order sums yield the same value. For $N^* = 1$ one gets the condition that $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ need to linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: If you let the $\lambda_i$ be linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, you will obtain the upper bound. That is, just pretend the $\lambda_i$ are unknowns, with no relations.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson I think you misunderstood the question.  What was wanted was an **upper** bound on the number of elements of $I_p$ that can have the same sum.  In your example that number is $1$, which is a lower bound.

Comment: Taking a set symmetric about  0, one get n/2 choose p/2 as a bigger lower bound. Since any two choices for the same sum will differ by at least two members, no choice of p-1 members is repeated, so that provides a weak upper bound.

Comment: Also, considering the first n whole numbers, there are np-p+1 possible sums, so that gives a lower bound not far from the weak upper bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I answer the first question in Corollary 4.1
of my paper at http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/42.pdf. The
maximum number of sums that have the same value is the middle
coefficient of the $q$-binomial coefficient $\left[ n+p-1\atop p
\right]$. This is achieved by taking $\Lambda=\{ 1,2,\dots,n\}$ and
the sum to be $\lfloor \frac 12 p(n+1)\rfloor$.  A more elementary
proof follows from the work of Proctor and is given in my book
*Algebraic Combinatorics*.

**Addendum.** For fixed $p$, it follows from http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/qbc.pdf that the middle coefficient of  $\left[ n+p-1\atop p\right]$ is asymptotic to 
   $$ \frac{A(p-1,\lceil p/2\rceil)n^{p-1}}{(p-1)!p!} $$
as $n\to \infty$, where $A(p-1,\lceil p/2\rceil)$ denotes an Eulerian number.

Comment: I always thought Corollary 4.1 of your paper applied to an arbitrary set of real numbers (not just a set of positive reals).  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Indeed, it seems like the general case can be deduced from the all $\lambda_i > 0$ case by adding a large positive constant $C$ to each $\lambda_i$.

Comment: You are right! I have corrected this.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not familiar with the notion of middle coefficient?

Comment: @Zeno44 Just note that the q-binomial coefficients are symmetric polynomials in q.

Comment: @Wolfgang : Thanks, the problem was that I wasn't even familiar with q-binomial coefficients! It seems that this middle coefficient is quite hard to compute in general? Can $\left[ n+p-1\atop p \right]$ be upper bounded by ${N+p-1} \choose p$ with some $N \le n$?

Comment: I would think so, but I have no idea how small N can be made in terms of n as n grows. It is related to the partition function, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#Applications.

Comment: @Wolfgang I ve tried some examples. So far $N \ge \frac{n}{2}$ was sufficient.

Comment: I think the middle coeeficient has degree $\frac12p(n-1)$ and the sum in question is $\frac12n(p+1)$ instead of $\frac12p(n+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

A trivial upper bound is ${n+p-1} \choose p$.  Somewhat less trivial is ${{n+p - 1} \choose p}/(p+1)$, which can be obtained as follows.
Suppose we put  the elements in increasing order.  Consider the "stars and bars" representation of $I_p$ (where if there are bars at positions
$1 \le b_1 < b_2 < \ldots < b_{n-1} \le n+p-1$, there are $b_1 - 1$
of $\lambda_1$, $b_2 - b_1$ of $\lambda_2$, ..., $b_{n-1} - b_{n-2}$ of $\lambda_{n-1}$ and $n+p-1 - b_{n-1}$ of $\lambda_n$). 
Suppose we put bars in vacant positions one-by-one.  Each of the $p+1$ possible positions for 
the last bar to be placed produces a different sum (each time you move it to the next available position to the right, you substitute a smaller $\lambda$ in place of a larger one and decrease the sum)).  So the probability of getting a particular sum is at most $1/(p+1)$.

This bound is actually attained in your example with $n = 3$ and $p = 2$.